# should test case names include numbers to maintain order in a tool like Spira or ALM

Tags: test-management

should test case names include numbers to maintain order in a tool like Spira or ALM

Users that came from Excel refuse to let go of the 1.01.001 1.01.002.... 
We have moved to a tool and automation of testing....

Answer (score 2):

A test case is a set of instructions to [exercise a particular test](http://www.kaner.com/pdfs/GoodTest.pdf).

Given that, since running the same test for the same UAT, **always** yields the same result, the order to execution of a series of test cases should not be important.

Order may be important for the execution organization itself (not the results). People may prefer to gather test cases for target feature, or for type of test goal, etc.

So, if the direction is to value people more than tools, people should be able to organize their documentation* as they please - since this organization is aimed at optimizing the work, not for non-necessary (political) compliance.

* Side note: Test cases are documentation - by itself, has no value. The gathering of information (testing) is what brings value.

Comment: Order of execution may or may not be important but we cannot assume in one way.

Comment: Although test cases should be as independent as possible.